# Read multiple json objects from a json file

Tags: asp.net, json, json.net

I have a file with multiple json objects.How can i read this in .net

I need the below string as two json obejcts

"{hello:'there'}   {goodbye:'you',Thanks:'you'}"

Comment: where is the parent object?

Comment: There is no parent object as these are two   json objects in a single file.This json file is generated from a system.The file contains two or more json objects.We have to read it and save it in a sql server database

Comment: but you cannot access objects individually , either place those jsons into an array or in a json object like [{hello:'there'},{goodbye:'you',Thanks:'you'}] , or {"hello":{hello:'there'},"greetings":{goodbye:'you',Thanks:'you'}}

Answer (score 1):

@Anu:  first of all, I do not think the string you specified "{hello:'there'} {goodbye:'you',Thanks:'you'}" is the proper Json string.

It should be like this one to deserialize properly
 **{"Arrival":{"Hello":"there"},"Departure":{"GoodBye":"you","Thanks":"you"}}**.

Take a look at the example below for proper structure:

[image]

//You need to install the Json.Net and use it as shown below:

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

//The object for Serializing and Deserializing:

```
public class Greeting
{

    public Arrival Arrival { get; set; }
    public Departure Departure { get; set; }
}

public class Arrival
{
    public string Hello { get; set; }

}

public class Departure
{
    public string GoodBye { get; set; }
    public string Thanks { get; set; }

}
```

//Populate the Getting Object C# way

```
var greeting = new Greeting
                {
                    Arrival = new Arrival { Hello = "there" },
                    Departure = new Departure { GoodBye = "you", Thanks = "you" }
                };
```

//Serialize the C# object to Json

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
                Arrival = new
                {
                    greeting.Arrival.Hello
                },
                Departure = new { greeting.Departure.GoodBye, greeting.Departure.Thanks }
            });
```

//Which produce this Json String: **{"Arrival":{"Hello":"there"},"Departure":{"GoodBye":"you","Thanks":"you"}}**

//Convert the Json string back to C# object - Deserialize the object

```
    var greeting1 = (Greeting)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString, typeof(Greeting));
```

Hope this helps and answered your question.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I cant create a typed class because json content will not be same always.My requirement is to read multiple pieces of json content from  single file.from this url https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_SupportMultipleContent.htm ,it is mentioned that it is possible to read multiple json pieces

Comment: If so then you have the answer from the link Brian Rogers provided.  Take a look, it just explains what you're looking for.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanx all..Brian Rogers is true.

Answer (score 1):

*Dibu* is right - your string is not a valid JSON object, so you can't deserialize it back to object(s) automatically.

You should either write your own parser (oops, don't do this) or force changing source input file to have one of:

1. Contain one valid JSON object (made of several separate objects), so you can deserialize it easily
2. Contain some separator(s) between individual objects, so you can split source string manually and deserialize objects one by one.

The best option is to change source file to contain one valid object, but I guess this was not your decision about such source file format...

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. You need a JsonConverter to pass when you deserialize.

```
string json = @"{hello:'there'} {goodbye:'you',Thanks:'you'}";

IList<Greeting> greetings= new List<Greeting>();
JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json));
// this is the important part, which makes the reader not throw exception
//when one json object is finished
reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;
while (true)
{
    if (!reader.Read())
    {
        break;
    }

    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    Greeting greeting= serializer.Deserialize<Greeting>(reader);

    greetings.Add(greeting);
}
```